# recyclerview linear layout responds to click only from half of it, but after scrolling it works fine

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview with each row made of a linear layout, and simple textview.

In the linear layout (which is the parent), I put an interface, with OnItemClickListener. Its working fine but...

The row is only clickable at the area where the text view is. However the rest of the area of the Linear Layout is not clickable. So when I click the blank area of the row, nothing happens. But when I scroll down the list a bit, for the items below it does work fine.

I hope its clear. Why is this.

Here is my adapter:

```
    public class SearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchItemViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<String> searchArrayList;
    private Context context;

    private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
         void onItemClick(String itemName);
    }


    public SearchAdapter(ArrayList<String> searchArrayList, Context context, OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        this.searchArrayList = searchArrayList;
        this.context = context;
        mOnItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public SearchItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.food_list_item_search_view, parent, false);

        return new SearchItemViewHolder(itemView);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SearchItemViewHolder holder, final int position) {


        final String currentItem = searchArrayList.get(position);

        holder.itemTextView.setText(currentItem);

        holder.searchItemLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(currentItem);
            }
        });




//        holder.setImage(holder.itemTextView.getContext(), holder.countryFlagImageView, currentCountry.getFlag());

    }

//    @Override
//    public void onViewRecycled(SearchItemViewHolder holder) {
//        super.onViewRecycled(holder);
//        holder.imageLoadTask.cancel(true);
//    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return searchArrayList.size();
    }





}
```

Here is my viewholder:

```
    public class SearchItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    TextView itemTextView;
    LinearLayout searchItemLinearLayout;


//    public LoadImage imageLoadTask;


    public SearchItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);


        itemTextView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.search_item_text_view);
        searchItemLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.search_item_linearlayout);

    }

//    public void setImage(Context context, ImageView imageView, int resource){
//        imageLoadTask = new LoadImage(context, imageView, resource);
//        imageLoadTask.execute();
//    }



}
```

Here is my xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/search_item_linearlayout"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"


    >




       <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Food item"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/search_item_text_view"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was happening because I was using Linear Layout and orietaion horizontal. When I changed it to relative layout, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make you parent layout clickable

```
android:clickable="true"
```

`ViewGroup`s are not by default clickable.